# Knockout binding wrapper, change in input does not fire observable subscription

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to write a trivial wrapper around KO textInput binding. The input is populated with the initial value "abc" however when I type any new value in the input, the corresponding observable does not update. What am I missing here? I am quite new to KO.

```
ko.bindingHandlers.myBind = {
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
  var test= ko.observable("abc");
  test.subscribe(function(newVal){console.log(newVal);});
  ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, test, allBindings);     
}
};
ko.applyBindings()

// html
<input data-bind="myBind" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueAccessor` argument must be a **function** that returns observable:

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.myBind = {
  init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindings) {
    var test= ko.observable("abc");
    test.subscribe(function(newVal){console.log(newVal);});
    var newValueAccessor = function(){ return test; };
    ko.bindingHandlers.textInput.init(element, newValueAccessor, allBindings);     
  }
};

ko.applyBindings();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="myBind" />
```